# Python: read a changeable XML file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Let's say I have this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from time import sleep

def get_src():
    while True:
        path = "input.xml"
        root = ET.parse(path).getroot()
        nodes = root.findall('body/video')
        for node in nodes:
            src = node.get('src')

            yield src

for i in get_src():
    print(i)
    sleep(3)
```

How can I get python to refresh `nodes`, when the content of the xml file is changing and while the loop is already running?

Comment: You should not change the value you are iterating over!

Comment: So in other words: in that way I have the sample, it is not working?

Comment: It could work but most likely it would not. Either way you will run into problems doing this rather earlier than later...

Comment: Ok, thank you! That is all I need to know. I have a another workaround for this case to, I only though mybe like this it would be more easy.

Comment: Why not just make it a rest service?